# Is it possible to send a console session from a terminal emulator to another under Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, kde-4, konsole

This is a bit odd question, maybe, but I would like to know if it is possible to move an active console session from a terminal emulator to another.

More specific, let's say that I'm using KDE and I've started some commands from [Yakuake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuake), but for some reason, I'd like to move the whole process directly into [Konsole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konsole) (or the other way around).
If I'm not wrong, Yakuake and Konsole are interfaces of the same backend, the Konsole Kpart, so basically it's the same program with two different interfaces. It makes me wonder if what I want to do is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly not. Each terminal you open runs a separate instance of your shell. They may indeed all be running the same shell but each instance is completely independent of the other, there is no communication between them.

A better question is be why would you want to? Just wait for the current process to finish, close one terminal and open the other. The `history` is shared between them.

Comment: Not a real need, it was just for the sake of knowledge. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do it with running processes...
But if you just planing to run something you can use tmux (or screen) in yakuake, detach from session, and attach to this session from konsole.

Yakuake:

```
$ tmux new
$ ./your_script
Ctrl+b d
```

Konsole:

```
$ tmux attach
```